# How to change user which is connected in SQL Developer for Oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, oracle12c

I created a user and granted it privileges but I cannot connect to the database as that user from SQL Developer.

When I enter the code in SQL*Plus it shows that it has connected as in the picture below

[image: picture]

However when I try the same thing in Oracle SQL Developer, it shows me SYS user.

[image]

How to fix this?

**EDIT**

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxFM6.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your SQL Developer screen shot you're looking at the 'Other Users' section of the navigation panel on the left, under your existing connection as SYS.

You *can* temporarily change to another user in that SQL Worksheet by doing:

```
connect c##murat/<password>
```

and then if you run as a script the statements after that will be performed as that user - and it will disconnect and revert to SYS when the script finishes.

But I wouldn't recommend that, except *maybe* as part of a schema-build script where you might want to switch back and forth. Particularly when you're really connected SYS. It's too easy to accidentally run something as the wrong user.

Really you need to create a new connection. At the top of the 'Connections' panel, click the green plus symbol and find your current connection in the list. Change the connection name (important!), username and password, set the role to 'default', click 'Test' to verify, and then click 'Save'.

You will then have two connections, and you can choose which to connect to and open SQL Worksheets as. As you're hopefully aware, you should not do any normal work as SYS, so you'll rarely need to connect as that again. I'd suggest you make it obvious in the connection name which is which, and that will appear in unsaved worksheet titles; and maybe use the connection colour option to further highlight and give you some visual warning when you are connecting as SYS.

When you are connected as your new user, you will not see their name in the 'Other Users' list. You will see SYS though.

Comment: can you look edit? when I set and clicked test as you said, I got failure

Comment: Did you select your existing connection first, and then overtype, as I said? It should have a service name not a SID for a start, in 12c. (I'm a bit confused by your new screenshot though; which connection were you using - did 'murat' connect as SYS?)

Comment: yes exactly. It was firstly set local/bequeath as connection type and sysdba as role. I guess  due to changing them I get failure

Comment: Did you get an error with local/bequeath? And why are you now trying to connect as `system` instead of `c##murat`? If you don't want SQL Developer to ever connect as SYS then you can change the credentials (and role) for your existing one, without changing the name, which will overwrite it.

Comment: yes , I don't know why but murat is connecting as sys

Comment: I also get same failure when I try c##murat for connection name, username and password by setting the connection type as basic and role as default

Comment: Why are you changing the connection type at all though? What happens with local/bequeath and your `c##murat` credentials? If you want to use a basic connection you'll need to set the service name (not sid) to the correct value, which you can get from the listener with `lsnrctl services`.

Comment: It's my fault. I entered wrong password for that! I finally connected. Thank you so much!

Comment: When you say `you can temporarily change to another user...`, how does one run additional commands as that user?  I can connect as another user that way (when the host/service name are appended), and it just responds with `Connection created by CONNECT script command disconnected`.   Perhaps you can expand your answer to show this.

Comment: @Gerrat - you need to run as a script (F5); if you run the `connect` as a statement (green arrow, or control-enter) then it runs in isolation and then yes it does disconnect again immediately. (I don't need to specify host/service, unless I actually want to connect to a different DB; it connects to the same as the current connection by default. Not sure if that's version-dependent.)

Comment: @AlexPoole - I get a jdbc error when I don't include the host/service.  Also tried the F5 with other DML. but just get the response I mentioned (even if I include complete garbage on additional lines).  I have the latest version of SQL developer, but maybe it's my Oracle version - 11.2 (or client version (12.2).